# Java: scanner not scanning complete lines

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the following text file (not a java file)

```
/*START OF CHANGES TO CODE*/
public class method1 {

    public static int addTwoNumbers(int one, int two){
        return one+two;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        int total = addTwoNumbers(1, 3);
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
/*END OF CHANGES TO CODE*/
```

I am trying to use the following code to read the file

```
String editedSection = null;
boolean containSection = false;
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(directoryToAddFile));
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
    if(in.nextLine().contains("/*START OF CHANGES TO CODE*/")) {
        containSection = true;
        editedSection = in.nextLine().toString();
    } else if (containSection == true) {
        editedSection = editedSection+in.nextLine().toString();
    } else if (in.nextLine().contains("/*END OF CHANGES TO CODE*/")) {
        containSection = false;
        editedSection = in.nextLine().toString();
    }
    in.nextLine();
}
```

So basically what i want it to do is read a file till it see's `/*START OF CHANGES TO CODE*/`, then start adding every line after this to a string till it reaches `/*END OD CHANGES TO CODE*/`. But when it is reading lines it ignores some lines and parts of others. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `in.nextLine()` *lots* of times within that `while` loop. That sounds like a really bad idea to me. How many times it will execute on each iteration will depend on which bits it went into... nasty.

I suggest you use

```
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    // Now use line for the whole of the loop body
}
```

That way you won't accidentally skip lines by reading them just for checking purposes.

Comment: that is exactly the problem, didnt even enter my head that it would move onto the next line ever time i called it... cheers :)